# Environment setup error - term 'call' is not recognized in PowerShell

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am a ROS beginner [installing ROS 2 on Windows](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Eloquent/Windows-Install-Binary/) and at the stage of [sourcing the ROS 2 setup file to set up the workspace](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Eloquent/Windows-Install-Binary/#environment-setup) in PowerShell. However, when I enter the command `call C:\dev\ros2_eloquent\local_setup.bat` (which I have verified to be the correct directory), I receive the following error:

```
call : The term 'call' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ call C:\dev\ros2_eloquent\local_setup.bat
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (call:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What should I do to solve this? Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347594/environment-setup-error---term-%27call%27-is-not-recognized-in-powershell/) by [Vuro H](https://answers.ros.org/users/52882/vuro-h/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2020-03-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These instructions are intended to be used with the `cmd` prompt.

If you want to use PowerShell you need to to invoke the setup file ending in `.ps1` (which is the extension for PowerShell scripts).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vuro H](https://answers.ros.org/users/52882/vuro-h/) on 2020-03-26**:
Thanks a lot, works well in `cmd`. How do I invoke the setup file ending in `.psl`?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-03-26**:
With just the filename.

**Comment by [jimmy_hawkins](https://answers.ros.org/users/109547/jimmy_hawkins/) on 2022-11-07**:
thanks you a lot, it worked for me as well.